# Cannot find system alert using Xcode Tests

Tags: swift, xctest, uialertcontroller

How do you tap on "OK" on the iOS system alert asking "Photos access" using Xcode Tests?

There are many many such questions on SO, but *none* of the answers worked for me.

Tests always fail - I.E. they cannot find the alert at all.

Xcode 13.4
Swift 5

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple tap on any alert would be:

```
XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard").buttons["OK"].tap()
```

If you want to ensure the correct alert is shown, you can build a more complex query like:

```
XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard").alerts.matching(NSPredicate(format: "label CONTAINS[c] %@", "Access Photos")).element.buttons["OK"].tap()
```

Comment: this does not work for Touch ID alert, the tests just hang

Comment: And not for the alert prompted by UIClipboard in UITest either. No solution yet. Sometimes apples privacy features makes it more fragile 

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for a notification alert either.